# Prevent user from changing programmatical selection in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView whose rows are selected/unselected based on filters set through other controls. This selection is ment to be only programmatical. How can I prevent user from changing these selections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of answering by telling you to keep `DataGridView1.Enabled = False`, which may work as per your need, but you might lose some visual effects(like greyed-out `DataGridView`).

Setting  `DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True` also won't help.

So the below code is not a perfect solution but more like a workaround to get exactly what you want (tested now & completely working):

```
Dim SelectedRows As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown

    For Each Rows As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        SelectedRows.Add(Rows)      'Add all the rows pre-defined by your code
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()  'clear the selection
    For Each rs As DataGridViewRow In SelectedRows
        rs.Selected = True          'restore the previous selected rows
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick

    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()  'clear the selection
    For Each rs As DataGridViewRow In SelectedRows
        rs.Selected = True          'restore the previous selected rows
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Something urgent came up here and it would take a time to test your suggestion, but I think until tomorrow maximum I come back with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible (without customizing DataGridView) to keep it enabled (so to see selection) and avoid user to be allowed to select rows. 
However, you can store your selection i.e. in a list(of int16) and handle events like CellClick and re-read and **reset the selection from the list every time the user clicks inside DataGridView**. Hopefully it won't be even noticeable to the user, but either way it will not allow him to modify the selection.